# WPF - How do force a binding update of an object's child property?

Tags: wpf, binding

I know similar questions have been asked many times before, but I have yet to find an answer to this particular angle, so here goes. Please forgive me if there is already an answer to this somewhere.

I have a WPF app that is built using MVVM (using the MvvmLight toolkit in case it makes any difference), in which one view model has several main properties. One of these goes by the snappy name of CurrentDhr, and is used as the DataContext of a tab. Many controls on that tab are bound to properties on the CurrentDhr object.

Now, if the CurrentDhr itself is updated, the binding is refreshed correctly. However, if I change a property on it, the binding it not updated at all. For example, the CurrentDhr has an int property called Revision, and if this is modified in the view model, the change does not show on the view.

How can I force the view to refresh? I can't call PropertyChanged, as that would only work for CurrentDhr itself, and as that hasn't changed, the binding won't be refreshed. I can't call PropertyChanged on CurrentDhr.Revision as this causes a run-time exception (no such property).

Anyone any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What is CurrentDhr? Is it an object of a class you created? Does that class implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: The definition of CurrentDhr would be helpful

Comment: Duh, dumb stupid me! This view model has a few objects pulled from the service layer, and all the others implement INotifyPropertyChanged. This particular one was previously only set when the view model first loaded its data, so didn't need to implement it (as the properties never changed). The current spate of changes required it to be changeable, and I forgot that it wouldn't raise the event. I added the interface and it works fine now! Thanks very much for the boot up the backside!

Comment: cheepdep, can I mark your reply as an answer? I voted for it, but that doesn't mark it. Not sure if I can do anything else to it.